# How to programatically alter "x-delta" of an Animation instance?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, shake

Let's say we want an animation that horizontally "shakes" a view.

We do something like this:

Java:

```
private void shakeView(final View v) {

        v.clearAnimation();

        Animation animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);

        v.startAnimation(animShake); 
}
```

xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="60"
        android:fromXDelta="-20"
        android:toXDelta="20"
        android:repeatCount="14"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
</set>
```

However, due to the fact that we are rigidly meticulous, we realize that the "shake distance" that is defined in xml is a static distance interpreted in dp/pixels, and therefore will be different on different devices -- on high resolution devices, the movement will be subtle... like an electric toothbrush, but on low resolution devices, the movement will be drastic like one of those flailing blowup dolls at a used car lot.

It would be far better to express the "x-delta" as a ratio of the view's width:

```
float ratio = 14f/392f;
float valueOfXTranslation = ratio*v.getWidth();
```

But... in order to do that we would have to be able to set the "x-delta" in code... and I see no way of doing that.

I have tried typing "animShake." -- "dot" -- and looking at the available options... and while there are a few setters, none of them seem to allow setting the "x-delta."  I suppose I should just give up and try  completely different approach using some other animation technique, but I just can't believe this would not be possible.

Is it possible to programatically alter the "x-delta" of an Animation instance?

Comment: Can't you use something like android:toXDelta="5%p"/android:fromXDelta="-5%p" to make it more unified between screensizes?

Comment: that's the answer! you should put it in and I'll award thee!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use optional %p in xml to control the amount of movement relative to the parent size. Like:

```
android:fromXDelta="-5%p"
android:toXDelta="5%p"
```

Comment: For me, I just did 5% with no 'p' ... but I was totally unaware of the fact that you could define percentages in the xml like that so THANKS!.

Comment: @BooberBunz yea, % is based on base size - %p on some parent container.